# Access TinyMCE content from Dart

Tags: dart, tinymce, dart-js-interop

I need to access TinyMCE content from Dart. The Dart js library should enable me to do so through TinyMCE's Javascript API. However, I'm stuck at how to initialize TinyMCE from Dart because I found no instruction on how to construct a TinyMCE instance in Javascript.

According to TinyMCE API, the following JS code should return TinyMCE content:

```
 tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
```

Thus, I believe this Dart code should do the same:

```
var content = js.tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
```

However, running this code returns the following error:

> Internal error: ...: Error: line 149 pos 20: identifier 'js.tinymce'
>   cannot be resolved   var content =
>   js.tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();

The editor complains about the undefined `tinymce` variable. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *js-interop* equivalent of *JavaScript* `tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();` is :

```dart
js.context.tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
```

Basically `js.context` returns a reference on the *JavaScript* `window` object.